# How to set a condition for the background color of a CheckBox in Mouse Over state?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate

I needed a `CheckBox` that acts as follows

- Unchecked - The default style is applies
- Checked - The background is blue and the check mark glyph is white

I created a template like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFF"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="checkBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                    <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3C77DD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FF3C77DD"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

The problem is when the mouse is over the `CheckBox` and it's unchecked, the background changes to blue, and if I change:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
```

to white, when it's checked and the mouse is over the `CheckBox` the background changes to white. How can I change the template so that the background is blue, if the `CheckBox` is checked and the mouse is over it and set the background to white, if it is unchecked and the mouse is over it?

Comment: Use a MltiTrigger that triggers on IsMousOver and IsChecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BionicCode already mentioned in the comments, you should use a [`MultiTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=net-5.0), which can use a set of conditions. The setters are only applied if **all** of the confitions are met.

```
<MultiTrigger>
   <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
      <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
   </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```